# Simple "If" Statements not working in keyTyped ()

Tags: java, applet

Im running this code, and It's giving me a huge problem. Without accepting any char from the user it just skips all the if statements, and changes the numOfCardsChosen to 5 automatically.

```
public void keyTyped (KeyEvent e)
{

    if (numOfCardsChosen == 0)
    {
        cardChosen1 = e.getKeyChar ();

        numOfCardsChosen++;
        cardChosen2 = e.getKeyChar ();
        System.out.println (numOfCardsChosen);
    }

    if (numOfCardsChosen == 1)
    {

        cardChosen2 = e.getKeyChar ();

        numOfCardsChosen = 2;
        System.out.println (numOfCardsChosen);

    }
    if (numOfCardsChosen == 2)
    {
        cardChosen3 = e.getKeyChar ();
        numOfCardsChosen = 3;
        System.out.println (numOfCardsChosen);

    }
    if (numOfCardsChosen == 3)
    {
        cardChosen4 = e.getKeyChar ();
        numOfCardsChosen = 4;
        System.out.println (numOfCardsChosen);
    }

    if (numOfCardsChosen == 4)
    {
        cardChosen5 = e.getKeyChar ();
        numOfCardsChosen = 5;
        System.out.println (numOfCardsChosen);
        repaint ();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this method even being called? Drop a print statement to make sure.

Comment: You need to debug this. Put in some breakpoints or more logging of values.

Comment: What is `numOfCardsChosen `?

Comment: `numOfCardsChosen` doesn't appear to be within the scope of `keyTyped()`.

Comment: it looks to me that no matter what numOfCardsChosen is inside your function it will fall through every if statement in the function resulting in numOfCardsChosen to = 5

Comment: If `numOfCardsChosen` starts at 0, every one of your if statements is going to run in order.

Comment: It makes no sense why it should do that. It doesn't fall through the first if statement, the rest after that.

Comment: @BilltheLizard I think the idea is that this method tops the number of cards up to 5.

Comment: @pbabcdefp It changes the variable in every if statement, then checks it again in the next if statement. No matter what value you start at, all if statements starting at that value are going to evaluate to `true` and `numOfCardsChosen` is going to end up equal to 5.

Comment: I don't know exactly what you mean... but is there a solution for me to achieve what I want, without that happening? @BilltheLizard

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @HisokaFreescs Can you please post some more code and/or put a `System.out.println(numOfCardsChosen);` at the top of the method to confirm it's even being called.

Comment: Ok I confirmed and yes it is being called, and I don't what more code could you want..., this is the only section that has to do with this. And numOfCardsChosen is a global variable.

Comment: @pbabcdefp you can't have a loop inside the keyTyped event handler and expect it to receive a different key in each iteration of the loop. I think the idea is to allow for 5 different cards to be chosen by pressing the key for each one at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to check only one of the if condition, then use `if-else if-else if-else-else`, instead of `if-if-if-if`.

@JRowan has answered your question in the comments of your question.

```
int i = 0;

if (i == 0) {
    System.out.println(i);
    i++;
}
if (i == 1) {
    System.out.println(i);
    i++;
}
if (i == 2) {
    System.out.println(i);
    i++;
}
```

Instead use

```
int i = 0;

if (i == 0) {
    System.out.println(i);
    i++;
} else if (i == 1) {
    System.out.println(i);
    i++;
} else if (i == 2) {
    System.out.println(i);
    i++;
}
```

**Note:** For this kind of scenario, first try to debug your code (either using break points or using logger). You will get cause of the problem from debugging itself.

Comment: "No, yes it is thank you" what does this even mean?  :(  say "yes" or "no" but not both!

Comment: Actually, I also got confused with that comment, that's why I put second comment confirming that if it answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, what is numOfCardsChosen? There is no declaration of this variable.  Additionally, how are you calling this method in your code? To capture the KeyEvent, you will definitely want this method call in a while loop.

Answer (score 0):

Several issues. First, your series of "if" statements each increment `numOfCardsChosen`, thereby making the condition for the next `if` statement true (assuming that the first condition is true). For example imagine that `numOfCardsChosen` is initially 0:

```
if (numOfCardsChosen == 0)
{
    // snipped
    numOfCardsChosen++; // <-- numOfCardsChosen is now 1
    // snipped
}

if (numOfCardsChosen == 1)   // <-- condition is now true
{
    numOfCardsChosen = 2;   // <-- numOfCardsChosen is now 2
}
if (numOfCardsChosen == 2)   // <-- so this is true
// etc
```

This could be solved by using 'else if' for the second and subsequent 'if' statements.

Secondly, you ask for the key character twice from the same event:

```
if (numOfCardsChosen == 0)
{
    cardChosen1 = e.getKeyChar ();   // <-- here you get the key character

    numOfCardsChosen++;
    cardChosen2 = e.getKeyChar ();   // <-- here you get it again
```

In the code snippet above, `cardChosen1` and `cardChosen2` will always be the same.